.run folder missing at project root
I am following this.
It mentions to put the configuration provided in .run folder. But I don't see any such folder in my project directory.
Where can I find it?

That documentation seems to be a bit outdated. Modern IntelliJ versions store the run configuration under .idea/runConfigurations.
